# Using Proxy System Wide Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, bittorrent, pac

I am using a headless ubuntu system which has no GUI. I want to use a [pac-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) proxy for my ubuntu. I also want to use it on deluge bittorent client

i am using this setting currently

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host 'http://localhost/proxy.pac'
```

this is the content of my .pac file:

```
function isPlainHostNameEx(host){
  return !(!!~host.indexOf('.') || !!~host.indexOf(':'));
}

function FindProxyForURL(url, host){
  var lhost = host.toLowerCase();
  host = lhost;
  IPNotation = /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/g;

  var direct = [
    "local", "dev", "ip", "box", "lvh.me", "ripe", "invalid",
    "intra", "intranet", "onion", "vcap.me", "127.0.0.1.xip.io",
    "smackaho.st", "localtest.me", "site", "ip"
  ]
  for(var i=0;i<direct.length;i++){
    if(dnsDomainIs(host, direct[i])){
      return "DIRECT";
    }
  }

  var CC = "DE";
  var exceptions = JSON.parse('[{"CC":"US"}]');

  for(var i=0;i<exceptions.length;i++){
    var e = exceptions[i];
    if(e.CC == CC) {
      for(var j=0;j<e.domains.length;j++){
        if(dnsDomainIs(host, e.domains[j])){
          return e.nodes;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return "12.024.04.10"
}
```

When I run `apt-get update` I get these errors:

```
 W: Failed to fetch http://stingray.cyber.net.pk/pub/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'stingray.cyber.net.pk'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the question? :/

Comment: This is pac script i want to use for my headless server. when i run apt-get update i get these errors W: Failed to fetch http://stingray.cyber.net.pk/pub/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'stingray.cyber.net.pk'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a little your question, trying to make it clearer. 
I admit I've never wrote a `.pac` file but it seems to me that the error may be related to the line

```
return "12.024.04.10"
```

I've not found any documentation on returning direct IP addresses from `FindProxyForURL`. Maybe you meant

```
return "PROXY 12.024.04.10";
```

additionally please check if `12.024.04.10` is reachable from your server.

finally please note that the block code

```
for(var i=0;i<exceptions.length;i++){
    var e = exceptions[i];
    if(e.CC == CC) {
      for(var j=0;j<e.domains.length;j++){
        if(dnsDomainIs(host, e.domains[j])){
          return e.nodes;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

will never return anything as long as `CC` and `exceptions` will be hard-defined into your code as you show us (`"DE"` and `'[{"CC":"US"}]'`, respectively), but if you are going to change the two variables please check that `return e.nodes;` will return a valid string as well (aka `"PROXY <some_ip>:<some_port>"`).

hope it helps :)

Comment: pac file is fine i edited some of the pac file inorder to preseve some proxy servers (in that process i might have changed some code). I can use it using foxy proxy in my machine but how can i use it system wide on headless machine.

Comment: I'm sorry then, I've difficult to understand what you are asking probably because I'm not an expert on this field but may I suggest you to check the answers to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/323488/ubuntu-system-wide-proxy-auto-configuration-pac-script and eventually this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy